# How to change UIButton state programmatically in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uicontrolstate

I develop app for drawing on screen. I have toolpanel with bunch of buttons. Some of them have to become disabled or pressed depending on current user action. How can I change UIControlState of buttons programmatically considering that "state" property is readonly? If it's impossible, what is alternative for this purpose?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I think you're confused. `UIControlState` is used to set up target/actions, or to change the appearance of the button for specific states (So, for example, you can specify the image that's used when it's selected, and a different image for when the button is not in the selected state.)

If you want to change the state to selected, you just set the selected property.

```
button.isSelected = true
```

Likewise for isEnabled:

```
button.isEnabled = false //disable the button
```

Answer (score 13):

Use the correct property to change the state. For example

```
button.isSelected = true
```

or

```
button.isHighlighted = true
```

Comment: This may be an old thread, but it looks like you beat me to the answer by a minute. I'm not sure why you didn't get the check or the votes, but I'm giving you my vote since you were first to answer correctly.

Comment: @DuncanC No problem for me. Im not searching for votes or checks, just want to help out people :) But thank you.